# Template instances with different return types

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++17

As per this document, which says that[emphasis mine]:

> ***The return type of a function has no effect on function overloading***, therefore the same function signature with different return type will not be overloaded. Example: if there are two functions: int sum() and float sum(), these two will generate a compile-time error as function overloading is not possible here.

It's amazing that [this code snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/rsPKsq3xE) works!

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
T foo(){return T{};}

template<>
int foo(){std::cout << "int" << std::endl; return int{};}

template<>
double foo(){std::cout << "double" << std::endl; return double{};}

int main() {
    foo<int>();
    foo<double>();
    foo<bool>();
}
```

You see, the [code snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/TYfK118z3) below does not compile indeed(If you have a question in it, please see the quotation at the beginning of the post):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

int foo(){std::cout << "int" << std::endl; return int{};}

double foo(){std::cout << "double" << std::endl; return double{};}

int main() {
}
```

Comment: You may want to formulate a question.

Comment: There's no overloading here, only specialization.

Comment: `foo<int>` and `foo<double>` are not the same function name

Comment: @aschepler It's legal to have functions with the same arguments and different return types?

Comment: @John They are not the same function. One is `foo<int>` and other is `foo<double>`. Also, you're specializing and not overloading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first snippet, you're providing two **specializations** of the more general **primary** function template `foo<T>`. In particular, you have provided specializations for `T=int` and `T=double` meaning we'll have `foo<int>` and `foo<double>` which are different from each other.

So in the 1st snippet there is no function overloading since the name are not the same in the first place. One is `foo<int>` and other is `foo<double>`.

From [function overloading 11.3.5.5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.fct#5)

> A **single name** can be used for several different functions in a single scope; this is function overloading.

More importantly, note that specializations instantiate a template; **they do not overload it**. As a result, **specializations do not affect function matching**.

Consider the following examples to illustrate the point:

**Example 1**

```
template <typename T>
T foo(T a, T b){return T{};}

template <>
int foo(int a, int b){return 4;}

int main()
{
    foo(5, 7.0); // error: no matching function for call to ‘foo(int, double)’ 
}
```

**Example 2**

```
template <typename T>
T foo(T a, T b){return T{};}

int foo(int a, int b){return 4;}

int main()
{
    foo(5, 7.0); // works fine 
}
```

---

On the other hand, in the 2nd snippet since the name of the function is the same, thus it is function overloading and we can't overload ordinary function just on the return type.

From [Overloadable declarations](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.load#2.1)

> Function declarations that differ only in the return type, the exception specification, or both cannot be overloaded.

Comment: The idea that the specializations have different names is a bit misleading: `foo<int>` isn’t actually a name, and it’s possible to do things like `static_cast<int(*)()>(foo)` that use the actual name `foo`.

Comment: @DavisHerring `foo<int>` is actually a name of the instantiated function. [Source](https://youtu.be/LMP_sxOaz6g?list=PLpHxZMy35Lo1255K3eSmjd161ra4vSnFT&t=619). Moreover, `foo<int>` and `foo<double>` are two different unique names.

Comment: We had to [change that](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.pre#4).  Name lookup doesn’t operate on *template-id*s, and it’s possible to construct distinct function template specializations that have the same template arguments and function types, so it’s better to say they just don’t have names.  Of course, informally a *template-id* can be **used** much like a name.